# How to track mmap calls by any application on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, mmap

Is there any way I can track mmap calls made by an application (for example: a Java application) running on Linux?

I am specifically looking to figure out how much memory an application (in this case - java application) is allocating through mmap calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at `/proc/{pid}/maps` If you poll it often enough you will be able to see changes.

Another option is to use `strace` to trace system calls to see them as they happen.

Comment: Thank you so much! I asked one more question as an extension to this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42091321/differentiate-between-java-application-mmaped-memory-and-jvm-mmapped-memory-on-l.